# C: splitting a string into a char[][] using delimeters while saving the delimeters

Tags: c, arrays, string

i have the string

`"this***is**my-beautiful--string"`

And i want to split this into

`{"this", "***", "is", "**", "my", "-", "beautiful", "--", "string"}`

There are two delimeters `"*-"` so I can use `strtok()` to find the words

but how can I add the delimeters into the array?

Comment: If `*` and `-` are the delimiters, why are they part of the tokens? Do you really want to split this string based on delimiters?

Comment: The problem is that when there are `*` before the string I have to do something different than when there are `-` before the string.

Comment: `strtok` will write a null character `'\0'` to your string, so you can't really use it here - after finding `"this"` the delimiter `"***"` will be partly overwritten. (And `strtok`doesn't patche up the string again after tokenising.)

Comment: @Dennis We don't know what you're trying to solve but wouldn't it be just easier to run through the string and do your checks?

Comment: Hmm maybe i will use a for loop then to put everything in the array

@HAL yes I think i go do that then

Comment: Whether you need to save the splitted string into separate array or you want to print according to the splitted value in terminal

Comment: You could make a copy of the string, use `strtok` on the original string, compute the starting offsets of the delimiter and find it with `strspn` on the string copy. But it's probably best to solve this directly without string library functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `strtok` here, because it "destroys" the delmiters in your input string by overwriting them with null characters. You can use the `strspn` and `strcspn` functions like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int xmain() {
    const char *str = "this***is**my-beautiful--string";
    const char *delim = "*-";

    const char *p = str;
    int mode = strchr(delim, *str) == 0;

    while (*p) {
        int n;

        if (mode) {
            n = strcspn(p, delim);
        } else {
            n = strspn(p, delim);
        }
        printf("'%.*s'\n", n, p);
        mode = !mode;
        p += n;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `mode` determined whether we are looking for a delimiter or for the text in between. Based on that, we have to look for the longest span of characters included (`mode == 0`) or not included (`mode == 1`) in the string of valid delmiters.

This code can be run on string literals. It does not yield zero-terminated C strings, however, but combinations of constant char ponters and string lengths. If you need to save your results in an array, I recommend saving them as a structure of pointer-plus-length data.

You can enforce starting your tokens with a (possibly empty) token or delimiter by initialising `mode` to 1 or 0, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you say you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PARSED_CHUNKS 4
struct parsed {
    char **data;
    size_t count;
    size_t alloc;
};

void allocate(struct parsed *p)
{
    if (p->count == p->alloc)
    {
        p->alloc += PARSED_CHUNKS;
        p->data = realloc(p->data, p->alloc * sizeof(char *));
        if (p->data == 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "no memory\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char *str = "this***is**my-beautiful--string";
    const char *start;
    unsigned int i;
    struct parsed p;

    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));

    for(;;)
    {
        allocate(&p);

        start = str;
        while(*str != '*' && *str != '-' && *str != '\0')
            str ++;
        if (str-start > 0)
            p.data[p.count++] = strndup(start, str-start);
        if (*str == '\0')
            break;

        allocate(&p);

        start = str;
        while(*str == '*' || *str == '-' && *str != '\0')
            str ++;
        p.data[p.count++] = strndup(start, str-start);
        if (*str == '\0')
            break;

    };

    for (i = 0; i < p.count; i++)
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, p.data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this program for easy understand.

```
#include"stdio.h"
#include"stdlib.h"
#include"string.h"
main()
{
    int i = 0 ,j = 0 ,k = 0,l=0;
    char string[]="this***is**my-beautiful--string";
    char *string1[9],tem[20];
    for ( i = 0 ; string[i] != '\0' ; i++ )
    {
            if ( isalpha(string[i] ) )
            {
                    if(l != 0)
                    {
                    tem[l] = '\0';
                    string1[k]=(char *)malloc(strlen(tem)+1);
                    strcpy(string1[k],tem);
                    k++;
                    l=0;
                    }
                    tem[j++]=string[i];
            }
            else
            {
                    if(j != 0)
                    {
                            tem[j] = '\0';
                            string1[k]=(char *)malloc(strlen(tem)+1);
                            strcpy(string1[k],tem);
                            k++;
                            j=0;
                    }
                            tem[l++]=string[i];
             }             
     }                                                  
    for ( i = 0 ; i < k ; i++ )
            printf("split string is :%s\n",string1[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the strtok() like this

```
char line[] = "this***is**my-beautiful--string";
char *token;
char *deli;
deli="*-";

token = strtok(line, deli);

while(token!=NULL){
    printf("%s",token);
    token = strtok(NULL,deli);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't save the delimiters which is exactly what the question is about.

Comment: @nwellnhof   oh yah actualy i am not getting the point my mistake and thanks